# Images layout in tumblr archive

Tags: css, image, tumblr

I want to reproduce the way the images are displayed in tumblr archive ([example](http://jeffreysimmons.tumblr.com/archive)).

More explicitly, I have, for instance, 10 images, and I want to display all of them as thumbnails images in a rectangle; the images have to be interleaved with each other.
I'm wondering which algorithm is used to calculate the size and the position of each thumbnails.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a site [HERE](http://computing.bournemouth.ac.uk/i7747061/assignment2/gallery.html) so think this gallery is the sort of thing your hoping for. The first thing you need to do is make the images the correct size. For this I use photohshop but any image editor will do. Create a document that all the images will fit on. Lay the images out how you want them and resize them accordingly. Use PhotoShops ruler tool to make sure the gap between each image is the same.

Once this is done save each image as that size. They are now proportional with each other. The CSS is simple I normally do it as percentages but pixels work fine too. if you have 10 images then you may want a 1% margin between each image that is 9% which leaves 91% left to split between each image, set the width to 9.1% each and that is your first row. For a better example here is the CSS and and html I used for the site linked above:

[HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/wNDeV/)

```
<section id="gallery">
        <div id="line_1">
            <div id="image_1">
                <a href="images/gallery_1.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_1.jpg" alt="Beach and yacht in the sun" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="image_2">
                <a href="images/gallery_5.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_2.jpg" alt="Cove - looking out to see" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
        <div id="line_2">
            <div id="image_3">
                <a href="images/gallery_4.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_3.jpg" alt="Blue skies, looking through  stair hole" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="line_2_2">
                <div id="image_4">
                    <a href="images/gallery_2.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_4.jpg" alt="beach and yacht at night" /></a>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                </div>
                <div id="line_2_3">
                    <div id="image_5">
                        <a href="images/gallery_6.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_5.jpg" alt="hills in the summer" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="image_6">
                        <a href="images/gallery_3.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_6.jpg" alt="Blue skies, looking through  stair hole different angle 2" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
        <div id="line_3">
            <div id="image_7">
                <a href="images/attractions_3.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_7.jpg" alt="Blue skies, looking through  stair hole different angle 3" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="image_8">
                <a href="images/about_3.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_8.jpg" alt="hills in the summer with person looking over village" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
        <div id="line_4">
            <div id="image_9">
                <a href="images/about_1.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_9.jpg" alt="little town in summer" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="image_10">
                <a href="images/attractions_2.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_10.jpg" alt="Looking at the castle from a distance" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="image_11">
                <a href="images/about_2.jpg" class="lightbox"><img style="width: 100%;" src="images/thumbnail_11.jpg" alt="very old photo of church with red door" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your precise example. I was hopping something more automatic because your way needs a bit of work.